# Specifing a attachment directory

Tags: corda

Is it possible to specify a specific directory location using the `services.uploadAttachment` that is provided by Corda, where does the uploaded file automatically be transferred to in the server after uploading?

Answer (score 0):

The attachment is not stored in a directory on the node. It is stored as a blob in the node's database.